# Does the System.Data.DataTable have a size limit?

Tags: .net, datatable

I'm adding data rows to my data table but the row count in the data table does not increase. Seems to be a limit of either size of the table or number of data rows.

FYI, .net 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(VS.80).aspx) to see the limitations of the datatable type. 16,777,216 is the maximum number of records.

Comment: Well, that's not my problem. I can't add more than 400 rows and I only have three columns of doubles (values ranging from 200'ish to 9000'ish). This seems like a pretty small data table.

Thanks. I'll keep digging. . .

Comment: I've seen a similar problem.  I don't have an exact count handy, but at some point in the low hundreds one of our apps starts dropping things from the data table.  Size really isn't that big, but seems like we're hitting some kind of limit somewhere.